# Using record classes with @RequestBean in Micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut, java-record

I am attempting to use Java records with `@Valid` and `@RequestBean` in Micronaut and am running into the following compilation error:

```
/Users/user/IdeaProjects/record_test/src/main/java/com/example/ReadController.java:16:28
java: Parameter of Primary Constructor (or @Creator Method) [id] for type [com.example.ReadBean] has one of @Bindable annotations. This is not supported.
  Note1: Primary constructor is a constructor that have parameters or is annotated with @Creator.
  Note2: In case you have multiple @Creator constructors, first is used as primary constructor.
```

My classes are as follows:

`ReadBean.java`:

```
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Nullable;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.PathVariable;

import javax.validation.constraints.Positive;

@Introspected
public record ReadBean(HttpRequest<?> httpRequest, @PathVariable @Nullable @Positive Integer id) {
}
```

`ReadController.java`:

```
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Produces;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.RequestBean;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller("/api/read")
public class ReadController {
    @Get
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public HttpResponse<?> read(@Valid @RequestBean ReadBean bean) {
        return HttpResponse.ok(bean);
    } //read
}
```

This error appears to be due to my use of `@PathVariable`. I can get around this error by explicitly declaring the canonical constructor in my record:

```
package com.example;

import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Introspected;
import io.micronaut.core.annotation.Nullable;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.PathVariable;

import javax.validation.constraints.Positive;

@Introspected
public record ReadBean(HttpRequest<?> httpRequest, @PathVariable @Nullable @Positive Integer id) {
    public ReadBean(HttpRequest<?> httpRequest, Integer id) {
        this.httpRequest = httpRequest;
        
        this.id = id;
    } //ReadBean
}
```

Is there any cleaner way to get around this? I recall that annotations on record components are propagated to the associated fields, constructors, etc. It would just be nice to not have to declare the constructor explicitly.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work without `@PathVariable` annotation?

Comment: @Denis That also doesn't seem to work. I'm getting the following error even though I am using `@Get(uris = {"/", "/{id}"})` now: `java: The route declares a uri variable named [id], but no corresponding method argument is present`

Comment: It might be worse to create an issue in Micronaut Core.

Comment: @Denis I'll do that. Thanks!